# Leiningen classpath issues, adding a second file to project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm currently trying to add a second file to my first leiningen project.

In pro/core.clj

```
(ns pro.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require ([pro.protocols :as prtcl])))

(extend-protocol prtcl.Matrix
...
```

In pro/protocols.clj

```
(ns pro.protocols)
(defprotocol Matrix
    "Protocol for working with 2d datastructures."
    (lookup [matrix i j])
    (update [matrix i j value])
    (rows [matrix])
    (cols [matrix])
    (dims [matrix]))
```

When running lein compile I keep getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   prtcl.Matrix, compiling:(pro/core.clj:8)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `prtcl/Matrix`, not `prtcl.Matrix`.

Comment: Thank you, but still not working,
what I'm gettin now is:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: prtcl

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Diego's answer, I hat to rewrite

```
(:require ([pro.protocols :as prtcl]))
```

to

```
(:require [pro.protocols :as prtcl])
```